# Multilinear Regression using OLS in Python not working with my own data

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Multiple Linear Regression using OLS code with specific data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458391/python-multiple-linear-regression-using-ols-code-with-specific-data)

Alright, I'm working with ols.py from scipy.org.  When I input my own variables and try to initiate a multilinear regression, I'm getting an error.

Every time I try to put my variables in place of the random variables that came with ols.py, it gives me an error.

For a good view on my error, I pasted the code on: http://pastebin.com/PGZvEUWn

The error is found on this line:

```
m = ols(y, x, y_varnm = 'y',x_varnm = ['x1','x2','x3'])
```

The error is writing:

```
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Any help would be great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The code is right except for the indentation in the methods of the class.